# Return value belonging to a key name matched by a glob expression in bash associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

that's my problem : i don't want use a switch but i want to use an associative array

do you know if i can use regex inside key of an associative array on bash.

For example i want that a key that match this regex

test*

has a value

1
and so on

so i want to create an associative array like this :

```
declare -a REPONAME=(
    [web*]=John
    [test*]=Luc
    [fra*]=Paul
)
```

but obviously it doesn't works. Can i use regex on keys?
Thanks

Comment: `declare -a` can't obviously work, because it doesn't create associative arrays in bash

Comment: You seem to be using a glob pattern rather than a regex. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand the requirement correctly, you want to match the keyname of against a known string and if a match is found, print the value belonging to the key.

Assuming you initialize an array right with `-A`. Note that your initialization of the array with the glob character is not needed. You can keep the key-names constant and compare it against your match string.

```
declare -A REPONAME=([web]=John [test]=Luc [fra]=Paul)
```

Doing below should work as expected. Note that I've used a glob expression `test*` which should be sufficient for your use case.

```
match=test
for key in "${!REPONAME[@]}"; do 
    [[ $key = "$match"* ]] && printf '%s\n' "${REPONAME[$key]}" 
done
```